# Let parent NSManagedObject's objectWillChange send value when relation object's property changed

Tags: swift, core-data, combine

On iOS 13 a `NSManagedObject`'s `objectWillChange` will emit when its property changes, but will not notify another `NSManagedObject` in the relationship.

My temporary workaround is the following:

```
class Child: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var parent: Parent?

    override func willSave() {
        super.willSave()
        if isUpdated {
            parent?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

This works. But in my case the model is more complex:

```
class Child: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var parent: Parent?

    override func willSave() {
        super.willSave()
        if isUpdated {
            parent?.objectWillChange.send()
            // NOTE
            // how to let grandParents objectWillChange also omit? 
        }
    }
}

class Parent: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var grandParents: Set<GrandParent>

    override func willSave() {
        super.willSave()
        // call grandParents forEach objectWillChange.send() if isUpdated
    }
}
```

At NOTE, I can iterate all `grandParent` of `parent` and send notification manually. But I believe there is a better, general solution can make that when an object is dirty, the parent will be marked dirty too. Then all object in the relationship will publish `objectWillChange` automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: I am assuming you are using SwiftUI. Can you add separate @ObservedObject to every NSManagedObject that you want your view is dependent on so that SwifUI can automatically update the view when the observed object changes.

Answer (score 0):

`objectWillChange` is for SwiftUI, to do this properly you need to learn KVO:

**Registering Dependent Keys**

*There are many situations in which the value of one property depends on that of one or more other attributes in another object. If the value of one attribute changes, then the value of the derived property should also be flagged for change. How you ensure that key-value observing notifications are posted for these dependent properties depends on the cardinality of the relationship.*

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE